# What API events are triggered when closing a FirefoxOS app

Tags: events

I need to check for unsaved data when a packaged app is closed (using the close button at the bottom of the screen and then pressing the X that is top left when the app appears reduced size).

I've managed to add an event listener for the low battery condition and this works as expected. But looking at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events I can't decide which event is correct for closing an app.

The obvious name -- close -- seems to be something to do with web sockets.

mozbrowserclose seems to be triggered when closing by the app's software.

XUL close "the user presses the close button" seems like the appropriate one, but when trying

```
window.addEventListener("close", function( event )
{
   window.alert("closing");
}, false);
```

the app closes without triggering the alert.

DOMWindowClose seems to be specific for close by window.close in software

mozbrowserclose seems to be specific to iframes

So ... does anybody know the correct event to trap ?

Phone is ZTE Open C with FFOS 1.3.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a bug -- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=996754 **"User-terminated apps do not receive 'beforeunload' event"**